# cypress reporter with multiple spec files

Tags: integration-testing, cypress

I have multiple spec files for running tests related to each other and to run them easier separately. When I run my cypress test with a junit reporter only test suites of the last spec files are present. We use the junit reporter for jenkins.

Is these some config I need to add to make sure all test suites are present in the junit report file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in cypress.  https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1824

You can use `[hash]` as a workaround to generate multiple test output files, jenkins will automatically compile the results together.

Add this to your `cypress.json` file:

```
"reporterOptions": {
        "mochaFile": "./cypress/results/cypress-output.[hash].xml"
    },
```

Comment: @MarceldeKoster did it work for you?  If so please accept the answer.

Comment: Took a while due to the development process to validate, but looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I was hunting for an answer to this question and just learned that if you use Mochawesome as your test reporter, you can use [Mochawesome Merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mochawesome-merge) to combine the output of multiple specs and then use [Mochawesome Report Generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mochawesome-report-generator) to create a single HTML report from your specs.